# How to access app resource files stored in 'src/main/resources/someFolder' within a Docker container?

Tags: java, json, docker, gradle, cloudant

I am working on a gradle based service that should run in a docker container in a kubernetes cluster. Locally, I can access the resources, some json files used for CouchDb initialisation. Once I build and deploy the service in Docker, the files are no longer accessible and I get file not found exception and can't start the service. I can see that my folder is in the generated jar but I can't access the files. 
I am using it like follows:

`DesignDocument design = DesignDocumentManager.fromFile("design-documents/documents.json");`

which comes from the [IBM Cloudant Java Client API](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.cloudant/cloudant-client/2.12.0). I have tried different versions from the path, i.e. with a leading slash or the absolute path from the project.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API does not have an alternative to File, which is an operating system File.
So use a temporary file.

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
        "/design-documents/documents.json");
Path tempPath = Files.createTempFile("desdoc-", ".json");
Files.copy(in, tempPath);
DesignDocument design = DesignDocumentManager.fromFile(tempPath.toFile());
Files.delete(tempPath);
```

Note the leading `/` for Class.getResource(AsStream).

Comment: that, worked for me, but we decided on another option, namely to copy the resource files into the container using COPY in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Hi, Can you share how you accessed the files in the COPY command? Looking to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

As @taz_ said, another way is to COPY the file from the resource in the Dockerfile

```
COPY src/main/resources/design-documents/documents.json /root/design-documents/documents.json
```

and then get it directly from there

```
DesignDocument design = DesignDocumentManager.fromFile("root/design-documents/documents.json");
```

In my case, I needed it as a String so this is what I did

```
public String readJsonAsString(String filePath) throws Exception {
    return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
}
```

The filePath was this

```
private static final String DOCUMENTS_JSON = "/root/design-documents/documents.json";
```